# connect pads together in footprint editor using copper polygon

Tags: kicad

There footprint of a part has several pads connected to each other through a shared copper fill. How would I assign the shared copper fill to be associated with the pads it's connected to? The problem I'm facing is that when I do a copper filled zone in the PCB editor there is no way for me to assign a net class to that shared copper fill so there it becomes an island.

For example, pads 9, 10, 11 are all connected together through a shared polygon. The polygon itself doesn't have a pad name. I created a filled zone with 0 clearance and solid pad connections and fill but it still avoids the copper polygon.

What's the best way to fix this? Should I make a custom sized pad for, let's say pad 9, and shape it to match the current polygon?

[image]

[image]

Version: 6.0.9-8da3e8f707~116~ubuntu22.04.1, release build

Comment: KiCAD seems to have a function for creating arbitrarily shaped pads: https://forum.kicad.info/t/create-pad-from-selected-shapes-solved/32770/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the footprint.  Select Pad 9, press Ctrl-E (Edit custom pad), then press Ctrl-E again.  This will form the custom pad with pad 9 as your anchor.

This being said, you are better served to have pads 9, 10 and 11 all being referred to as pad 9 if they are connected like this on the footprint.  The symbol should have only one pin (9) that refers to multiple landing pads.